# cat: /tmp/st.socket No such device or address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, unix, ubuntu-11.04

I am getting this report when i use the cat to view files within the /tmp directory.

cat /tmp/st.socket

***cat:  /tmp/st.socket No such device or address***

Cheers

Comment: What is its type? What does `ls -l /tmp/st.socket` show?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ls -l give me this:                                     srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-18 23:19  /tmp/st.socket

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You (via `cat`) are trying to open and read a [UNIX domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) and that is not how they are properly accessed.  Sockets are used by client/server processes to exchange data.  They must be accessed with different system calls than open(); you only get a failure with errno == ENXIO "No such device or address" if you use open().

If you `ls -l /tmp/st.socket` you'll likely see something like

```
srwxrwxrwx    1 root    root            0 Jan 24  2012 /tmp/st.socket
```

The 's' at the beginning of the line indicates that /tmp/st.socket is a socket.